# Nativescript plugin - Communication with third party native library

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-plugin

quick help if you can. Trying to implement calls to third party native function that accepts an object that has to implement a certain interface with a callback function. How exactly would you create an object like that on the Nativescript side and pass it to that native function?

Java example:

```
public class Logger {
    public static void setListener(LogListener listener) {
        // native code
    }
}

public interface LogListener {
    void onMessageLogged(LogMessage message);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want to pass in a `LogListener` to `setListener`?

In TypeScript that would be:

```
const myLogListener = new change.packagename.LogListener({
   onMessageLogged: message => {
     console.log(message);
   }
});

logger.setListener(myLogListener);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but that doesn't seem to work. LogListener is declared as an interface in the Java library and not as a class so I get an error when trying to instantiate using "new" keyword. So the real question here is how can I create a class on Typescript and pass it to the Java library so that it accepts it as an implementation of the LogListener interface.

Comment: That's strange.. take a look at this example of a Listener interface: https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/nativescript-mapbox/blob/60845febd4dee237fe5f20ef54c52025a413f387/src/mapbox.android.ts#L264-L274

Comment: After rechecking I saw a typo in the way the class was being created. I'll set this answer as correct. thanks.